# Cocoon how to remove associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, associations, assets, cocoon-gem

I am trying to use the Cocoon gem to add/remove `assets` on `asset_profiles`. Everything up to this point works, I am just having a problem with `link_to_remove_association`. When the button is clicked, the field is removed. But if the field had been filled in and saved previously, I am unable to remove said association. The button just hides the field until I hit update. Is there a way to actually remove the association from the database through `link_to_remove_association`? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am referring to:

Asset.show

```
= simple_form_for([@asset_profile, @asset]) do |f|
  = f.input :max_users, as: :hidden
  #assets_users
    = f.simple_fields_for :assets_users do |assets_user|
      = render "assets_user_fields", f: assets_user
    .links
      = link_to_add_association "Add Another User", f, :assets_users
    = f.submit
```

Asset._assets_users_fields

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :user_id, collection: @users.order(:last_name), :label => "User"
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f
```

Screenshot of page pre-remove:
[image: pre-remove]
Screenshot of post-remove:
[image: post-remove]
Screenshot of post-update(page reload):
[image: post-update]

I would much rather, after the update, the page be reloaded and looking like below, which is the form for initially adding users to an asset:
[image: new asset users]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using strong parameters, you have to make sure to permit `:id` and `:_destroy`, as documented by the way (see [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#strong-parameters-gotcha) ).

It is not unlogical: cocoon sets the `_destroy` if something needs to be removed, rails then needs the id to know what to remove.

Answer (score 4):

Im my case, i forget for `allow_destroy: true`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you permit the nested parameter _destroy in either `permit` (strong_parameters) or `attr_acceptible`?

Your `asset_profile_params` should look like

```
def asset_profile_params
  params.require(:asset_profile).permit(:max_users, :asset_users_attributes => {:user_id, :_destroy})
end
```